# How do you specify node result order?

Tags: c#, sorting, xpath

I have the following XML, which is generated by a 3rd-party library:

```
<PhoneNumbers>
    <PhoneNumber Key="1">123-456-7890</PhoneNumber>
    <PhoneNumber Key="2">234-567-8901</PhoneNumber>
    <PhoneNumber Key="3">345-678-9012</PhoneNumber>
</PhoneNumbers>
```

The issue is that I should not depend on the values of the `Key` attribute (a) appearing in order, or (b) beginning at 1. More so the latter, but I want this processing to be as safe as possible.

What I need to do is get a list of the phone numbers, sorted by the `Key` value (ascending). So by using `XmlNode.SelectNodes` I would like the resulting `XmlNodeList` to contain the `PhoneNumber` nodes in the proper order, not necessarily in the order they appear.

How can this be accomplished using XPath?
Is this possible to do it directly?

If it makes a difference, I'm using .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xpath itself does not define anything for that.

For C#.NET, this may be what you're looking for:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/ba975e0e-e0c7-4868-9acc-11d589cafc70/

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier in this particular case to select the phone## into a string list and then sort it?

Answer (score 4):

The XPathExpression class provides an AddSort method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This can't be accomplished with XPath.  If you were using an `XPathDocument` you could use the `AddSort` method.

However if you are already using XmlDocument (and/or need to be able to update the XML DOM) its probably just a easy to dump the result of SelectNodes into a `SortedDictionary` using the value of the Key attribute as the Key value.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how to do it with XPathExpression using the AddSort method already mentioned.  XPathExpression is available with.Net 2.0 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression.aspx)

```
private static void XmlTest()
{
    XPathDocument results = new XPathDocument(@"c:\temp\temp.xml");
    XPathNavigator navigator = results.CreateNavigator();
    XPathExpression selectExpression = navigator.Compile("/PhoneNumbers/PhoneNumber");
    XPathExpression sortExpr = navigator.Compile("@Key");
    selectExpression.AddSort(sortExpr, XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Text);
    XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator = navigator.Select(selectExpression);
    int i = 0;
    while (nodeIterator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nodeIterator.Current.Value);
        i++;
    }
}
```